# How assigned id to item in spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have `Spinner`, it has got a some items from parse JSON. JSON send in my app "statusId" and "statusTitle". How I can set my JSON "statusID" to "statusTitle", so in next step I could  call `getSelectItem` with my "statusId"?

`getSelectItemId` unsuitable in this situation, because different "statusId" and "positioId".

P.S. Please don't take my question is strictly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Save both of them in different Arraylist like this.

```
    ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<>();
    title.add("A");
    title.add("B");
    title.add("C");
    title.add("D");

    ArrayList<Integer> id = new ArrayList<>();
    id.add(1);
    id.add(2);
    id.add(3);
    id.add(4);
```

Now title A has id 1, B has id 2 and so on. Now whenever you select any of the item. Get it's position and check the item in both arraylist at that position. You will get both id and title

```
 title.get(position of selected item);
 id.get(position of selected item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class to list your items in the spinner:

```
public class Item {
   public int id;
   public String label;

   @Override
   public String toString() { return label; }
}
```

add an ArrayList or an Array of Item to your ArrayAdapter and so add your adapter to the spinner.

To get selected item from the spinner:

```
Item item = (Item) spinner.getSelectedItem();
```

and access to id with item.id

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with ItemName and ItemId like this:

```
public class EncapTest {
   private String name;
   private String idNum;



   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public String getIdNum() {
      return idNum;
   }


   public void setName(String newName) {
      name = newName;
   }

   public void setIdNum( String newId) {
      idNum = newId;
   }
}
```

and populate this using a custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I create a class to save the key value and then create an adapter.

To populate the spinner you can do something like that:

```
Spinner keyValueSpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_key_value);

KeyValueArrayAdapter adapter = new KeyValueArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapter.setEntries(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.statusTitle));
adapter.setEntryValues(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.statusId));

keyValueSpinner.setAdapter(adapter)
```

Note that in this example populate the adapter with arrays inside in the array.xml in resources. But you can populate  with `String []` if you would.

and the class adapter **KeyValueArrayAdaper.java**

```
public class KeyValueArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<KeyValueArrayAdapter.KeyValue> {

    /**
     * Key and Value
     */
    public class KeyValue {
        public String key;
        public String value;

        /**
         * @param key
         * @param value
         */
        public KeyValue(final String key, final String value) {
            super();
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param resource
     * @param textViewResourceId
     * @param objects
     */
    public KeyValueArrayAdapter(final Context context, final int resource,
                                final int textViewResourceId,
                                final KeyValue[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param resource
     * @param textViewResourceId
     * @param objects
     */
    public KeyValueArrayAdapter(final Context context, final int resource,
                                final int textViewResourceId,
                                final List<KeyValue> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param resource
     * @param textViewResourceId
     */
    public KeyValueArrayAdapter(final Context context, final int resource,
                                final int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param textViewResourceId
     * @param objects
     */
    public KeyValueArrayAdapter(final Context context, final int textViewResourceId,
                                final KeyValue[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param textViewResourceId
     * @param objects
     */
    public KeyValueArrayAdapter(final Context context, final int textViewResourceId,
                                final List<KeyValue> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param textViewResourceId
     */
    public KeyValueArrayAdapter(final Context context, final int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    /**
     * Change the string value of the TextView with the value of the KeyValue.
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        view.setText(getItem(position).value);
        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Change the string value of the TextView with the value of the KeyValue.
     */
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final TextView view = (TextView) super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);

        view.setText(getItem(position).value);
        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Set the specified Collection at the array.
     *
     * @param keys
     * @param vaules
     */
    public void setKeyValue(final String[] keys, final String[] vaules) {
        if (keys.length != vaules.length) {
            throw new RuntimeException("The length of keys and values is not in agreement.");
        }

        final int N = keys.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            add(new KeyValue(keys[i], vaules[i]));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the specified Collection at the array.
     *
     * @param keysVaules
     */
    public void setKeyValue(final String[][] keysVaules) {
        final int N = keysVaules.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            add(new KeyValue(keysVaules[i][0], keysVaules[i][1]));
        }
    }

    private String[] entries;
    private String[] entryValues;

    /**
     * Set the specified Collection at the array.
     *
     * @param entries
     */
    public void setEntries(final String[] entries) {
        this.entries = entries;
        if (entryValues != null) {
            setKeyValue(entryValues, entries);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the specified Collection at the array.
     *
     * @param entryValues
     */
    public void setEntryValues(final String[] entryValues) {
        this.entryValues = entryValues;
        if (entries != null) {
            setKeyValue(entryValues, entries);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the KeyValue with the specified position in the data set.
     *
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    public String getValue(final int position) {
        return getItem(position).value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the key of the KeyValue with the specified position in the data set.
     *
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    public String getKey(final int position) {
        return getItem(position).key;
    }

    /**
     * Get the entry of the KeyValue with the specified position in the data set.
     *
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    public String getEntry(final int position) {
        return getValue(position);
    }

    /**
     * Get the entry value of the KeyValue with the specified position in the data set.
     *
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    public String getEntryValue(final int position) {
        return getKey(position);
    }

}
```